# JavaScript not working when clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make the div slide up or slide back down when clicked, but nothing is happening when I click. I'm following a tutorial and I checked everything and can't seem to find the problem. Please help and explain what I'm doing wrong, I'm learning and I make a lot of silly mistakes so don't hate :)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
<script src="/assets/jquery.js"></script>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Londrina+Shadow' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<style>
body {
  font-family: helvetica, sans-serif;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 600px;
  background: #232323;
}
div {
  height: 200px;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  margin: 40px 0 0 0;
  border-radius: 12px;
}
h1 {
  font-family: 'Londrina Shadow', cursive;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 75px;
  color: #aaaaaa;
  margin: 60px 0 0 0;
}
h2 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #bbbbbb;
  margin: 0px 0 70px 0;
}
p {
  color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
  background: black;
  background: linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(0,0,0,1), rgba(0,0,0,.4));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(0,0,0,1), rgba(0,0,0,.4));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(0,0,0,1), rgba(0,0,0,.4));
  padding: 10px;
  line-height: 28px;
  text-align: justify;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 30px;
}
small{
  opacity: 0;
}
.show-description p{
  height: 150px;
}
.show-description small{
  opacity: 1;
}

.first{
  background-image: url("http://dash.ga.co/assets/firstcourse.jpg");
}
.second{
  background-image: url("http://dash.ga.co/assets/secondcourse.jpg");
}
.dessert{
  background-image: url("http://dash.ga.co/assets/dessertcourse.jpg");
}
.price {
  float: right;
}
@media (max-width: 500px){
  h1{
    font-size: 50px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    line-height: 40px;
  }
  h2{
    font-size: 20px;
    margin: 20px 0 30px 0;
  }
  div{
    margin: 20px 12px 0 12px;
  }
  p{
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 24px;
  }
  small{
    font-size: 16px;
  }
}
</style>

</head>

<body>
<h1>esha's restaurant</h1>
<h2>a New York City eatery</h2>
<div class="first">
  <p>welsh onion soko <span class="price">$14</span><br />
  <small>Mustard sierra leone bologi kale chard beet greens black-eyed pea sorrel amaranth garlic tigernut spring onion summer purslane asparagus lentil. </small></p>
</div>

<div class="second show-description">
  <p>pastrami boudin tongue <span class="price">$22</span><br />
  <small>Tri-tip capicola kielbasa salami brisket chicken rump strip steak drumstick. Meatloaf chuck boudin ribeye pork jowl. Andouille bacon jowl meatloaf pork loin prosciutto bresaola.</small></p>
</div>
  
<div class="dessert">
  <p>fruitcake marzipan pudding dragee <span class="price">$8</span><br />
  <small>Lollipop tart cotton candy jelly-o carrot cake apple pie cupcake. Jelly-o bear claw ice cream candy canes.</small></p>
</div>
<script>
$('div').on('click', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('show-description');
});
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in your javascript console? Seems to work here: https://jsfiddle.net/veke9ypg/. Perhaps your jquery isn't sourced right.

Comment: Post a link to the Tutorial?

Comment: @CoryTrese Seems like a mistake in the tutorial. I'm just following the steps from https://dash.generalassemb.ly/projects

Comment: I agree with @smerny.  I transferred the code to a codepen and it seems to work fine for me. Perhaps you are not loading your main jquery correctly http://codepen.io/LOTUSMS/pen/PNGGQX

Comment: @LOTUSMS I fixed my jquery source and it works now.

Comment: You should learn to check your javascript console, it basically would have told you it couldn't find jquery.

Comment: @smerny is right. Checking your console will let you know a lot of problems in your code and you can't learn if don't learn how to debug. Another thing you should get familiar with is Console.log() Web API. You can use this to talk to the console and trace a bug more specifically so that you know exactly where it is.

Comment: @smerny I somehow forgot to check it in the console, thanks for reminding.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, make sure your add-ons are not interfering. I had to disable some ad-blocking. And yes, I found out thanks to the console, so thank you for everyone for your comments about that.

I don't think it's necessary to change the source of the library if you followed the tutorial letter-by-letter.